# Small question about inductive proof about rational sequences

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, induction

I am writing an inductive proof about this:

[image]

the description is not terribly important so you don't have to read that.

here's my question:

let $P(n)$ be the statement that $x_n$ is a rational number in this sequence for all $x_1, a \in \mathbb{Q}$

now, what should I take as the base case? using what I have, the most logical thing seems to take $P(2)$, which involves $x_1$ which we know is rational. But this doesn't allow me to use the base case in the inductive case (which I am not so sure is required, but gives the proof more.. elegance?)

in any case, the argument in both cases is really easy, it's just that Q is a field so since all entries involved are rational and each operation in use is closed we can conclude that the resultant number is also rational.

Comment: The base case is $n=1$. We should prove (trivial) during the induction that the $x_i$ are positive.

Comment: So that's really working backwards in some sense, I know that $x_1$ is rational but I don't know anything about $x_0$. 

Why do we require $x_i$ positive?

Comment: There is no $x_0$. They started indexing at $1$.

Comment: alright then - can you write out the base case for me? I seem to have a misunderstanding.

Comment: $P(n)$ is the assertion that $x_n$ is a positive rational. The base case $P(1)$ is the assertion that our starting estimate $x_1$ is a positive rational. We have been told that $P(1)$ is true. As to why require positive, we don't really need positive, but we do need $x_i\ne 0$, else the iteration doesn't work.

Comment: Well that's one hell of an easy base case.

I suppose that allows me to avoid using the sloppy "Q is a field" argument and truly use induction here. Thanks!

Comment: Well, you are still using the fact that if $x_k$ is rational, and $a$ is rational, then $\frac{x_k^2+a}{2x_k}$ is rational. And yes, it is an easy base case, but they are seldom hard.

Comment: now that i'm writing it out, you're right, I have to use that Q is a field.

Comment: btw @AndréNicolas, this was a 3 part problem, and im on the second part now, which is the trivial thing you said: show that for $x_1 > 0$ all sequence elements are positive. so i'm not surprised this came up.

not asking for help on this one just making a note that what you said came up in this problem. I know that the idea of this problem is to show that this sequence converges to the square root of $a$ and give us a basis to construct $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P(n)$ be the assertion that if $n\ge 1$, then $x_n$ is a non-zero rational. We are told that $x_1$ is a non-zero rational, so that settles the base case.

For the induction step, suppose that $x_k$ is a non-zero rational. Then since $x_k^2+a$ is a positive rational, it follows that $\frac{x_k^2+a}{2x_k}$ is a non-zero rational.